# Performance of a bootstrap

Tags: r, bootstrap, simulation

In the context of a simulation study, for a bootstrap methodology to estimate a parameter:

Should a lots of bootstrap (but each one have a few resamples) be favoured over doing few bootstrap (but each one have a lots of resamples)?

Answer (score 0):

In general, each bootstrap resample consists of $N$ observations (sampled with replacement) from the original data set (which is also of size $N$). That is, each bootstrap resample has the same size as the original data set.

Regarding the number of bootstrap resamples to use, it will depend on the size of your original data set as well as what you are doing in each bootstrap iteration. These two things will dictate how fast each iteration is. You should find a good balance that gives you stable results and doesn't take too long to run. In my experience, anything above 500 bootstrap resamples tends to yield decent results, but it will ultimately depend on the characteristics of your data and objective. If your data isn't too big and you are not doing anything too computationally expensive in each iteration, using 10,000 bootstrap resamples seems to be the default for many people.